# Can not bind soap request with "Mulriref" in spring boot, How to fix?

Tags: spring-boot, soap

I try to migrate soap web service from Axis1 to Spring boot, but i cannot bind a request that contain "multiref" tag.
can someone tell me how to fix it ? , thank

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>

   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:holidayService soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://service.inbound">
         <requestMessage href="#id0"/>
      </ns1:holidayService>
      <multiRef id="id0" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns2:RequestMessage" xmlns:ns2="http://service.inbound" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <operation xsi:type="xsd:string">INQUIRY</operation>
         <requestData href="#id1"/>
      </multiRef>
      <multiRef id="id1" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns3:RequestData" xmlns:ns3="http://service.inbound" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <bankCode xsi:type="xsd:string">R01</bankCode>
         <initialYear href="#id2"/>
         <sponsorCode xsi:type="xsd:string">TE001</sponsorCode>
      </multiRef>
      <multiRef id="id2" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="xsd:int" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">2019</multiRef>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I found solution with Interceptor "TransformerObjectSupport" this is my solution**

1 Add xsl stylesheet file for transforming process

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" >

<xsl:key name="multiref-by-id" match="multiRef" use="@id"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(@href, '#')]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* |
         key('multiref-by-id', substring-after(@href, '#'))/@* |
        key('multiref-by-id', substring-after(@href, '#'))/node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@href[starts-with(., '#')] | multiRef[@id] | @soapenc:root"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

2 Add Interceptor for transforms payload

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement;

import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Templates;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory;

import escf.util.MessageDisplyFilter;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;
import org.springframework.ws.WebServiceMessage;
import org.springframework.ws.context.MessageContext;
import org.springframework.ws.server.EndpointInterceptor;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapBody;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapFault;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessage;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage;
import org.springframework.xml.transform.ResourceSource;
import org.springframework.xml.transform.TransformerObjectSupport;
import org.w3c.dom.Attr;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class RequestTransformingInterceptor extends TransformerObjectSupport
    implements EndpointInterceptor, InitializingBean {

private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(RequestTransformingInterceptor.class);

private Resource requestXslt;

private Resource responseXslt;

private Templates requestTemplates;

private Templates responseTemplates;
private String att;

/** Sets the XSLT stylesheet to use for transforming incoming request. */
public void setRequestXslt(Resource requestXslt) {
    this.requestXslt = requestXslt;
}

/** Sets the XSLT stylesheet to use for transforming outgoing responses. */
public void setResponseXslt(Resource responseXslt) {
    this.responseXslt = responseXslt;
}

/**
 * Transforms the request message in the given message context using a provided
 * stylesheet. Transformation only occurs if the {@code requestXslt} has been
 * set.
 *
 * @param messageContext
 *            the message context
 * @return always returns {@code true}
 * @see #setRequestXslt(org.springframework.core.io.Resource)
 */
@Override
public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception {`enter code here`
    if (requestTemplates != null) {
        WebServiceMessage request = messageContext.getRequest();
        SaajSoapMessage saajSoapMessage = (SaajSoapMessage) messageContext.getRequest();
        NodeList nodeList = saajSoapMessage.getSaajMessage().getSOAPPart().getChildNodes();
        Node node1 = nodeList.item(0);
        NamedNodeMap nodeAttributes = node1.getAttributes();
        Node nodeAttribu = nodeAttributes.item(0);
        Attr el = (Attr) nodeAttribu;
        int length = nodeAttributes.getLength();
        att = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            el = (Attr) nodeAttributes.item(i);
            if (att == null) {
                att = el + "";
            } else {
                att = att + " " + el;
            }

        }

        Transformer transformer = requestTemplates.newTransformer();
        transformMessage(request, transformer);
        logger.debug("Request message transformed");
    }
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception {
    if (responseTemplates != null) {
        WebServiceMessage response = messageContext.getResponse();
        Transformer transformer = responseTemplates.newTransformer();
        transformMessage(response, transformer);
        logger.debug("Response message transformed");
    }
    return true;
}

private void transformMessage(WebServiceMessage message, Transformer transformer) throws Exception {

    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    message.writeTo(buffer);
    String SOAPMessageRequest = buffer.toString(java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    String bodyMessage = SOAPMessageRequest.split("Body>")[1].replace("</soapenv:", "").trim();
    bodyMessage = bodyMessage.replaceFirst("soapenv:encodingStyle", att + " soapenv:encodingStyle").replace("\r",
            "");
    String[] bodyArr = bodyMessage.split("\n");
    SaajSoapMessage saajSoapMessage = (SaajSoapMessage) message;
    SOAPBody body = saajSoapMessage.getSaajMessage().getSOAPBody();
    String firstTagName = getFirstBodyElement(body);
    String lastTag = "</" + firstTagName + ">";
    for (int i = 0; i < bodyArr.length; i++) {
        String tag = bodyArr[i];
        if (tag != null && tag.startsWith("</") && tag.contains(firstTagName)) {
            lastTag = tag;
        }
    }

    bodyMessage = bodyMessage.replace(lastTag, "") + "\n" + lastTag;
    ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bodyMessage.getBytes());
    transform(new StreamSource(is), message.getPayloadResult());

    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    transformer.transform(message.getPayloadSource(), new StreamResult(os));
    is = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());
    transform(new StreamSource(is), message.getPayloadResult());

}


/** Does nothing by default. Faults are not transformed. */
@Override
public boolean handleFault(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception {
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    if (messageContext.getResponse() instanceof SoapMessage) {
        SaajSoapMessage soapMessage = (SaajSoapMessage)messageContext.getResponse();
        SoapBody body = soapMessage.getSoapBody();
        SoapFault fault = body.getFault();
        String faultstring = fault.getFaultStringOrReason();
        String faultCode =  fault.getFaultCode().getPrefix()+":"+fault.getFaultCode().getLocalPart();
        MessageDisplyFilter filter = new MessageDisplyFilter();
        stringWriter.append("<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><SOAP-ENV:Header /><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>").append(faultCode).append("</faultcode><faultstring xml:lang=\"en\">");
        stringWriter.append(filter.filter(faultstring));
        stringWriter.append("</faultstring></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>");
        Source source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(stringWriter.toString()));
        transform(source, body.getPayloadResult());
        stringWriter.close();

    }
    return true;
}

/** Does nothing by default. */
@Override
public void afterCompletion(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint, Exception ex) {
}

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    if (requestXslt == null && responseXslt == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Setting either 'requestXslt' or 'responseXslt' is required");
    }
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = getTransformerFactory();
    XMLReader xmlReader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
    xmlReader.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespace-prefixes", true);
    if (requestXslt != null) {
        Assert.isTrue(requestXslt.exists(), "requestXslt \"" + requestXslt + "\" does not exit");
        if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
            logger.info("Transforming request using " + requestXslt);
        }
        Source requestSource = new ResourceSource(xmlReader, requestXslt);
        requestTemplates = transformerFactory.newTemplates(requestSource);
    }
    if (responseXslt != null) {
        Assert.isTrue(responseXslt.exists(), "responseXslt \"" + responseXslt + "\" does not exit");
        if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
            logger.info("Transforming response using " + responseXslt);
        }
        Source responseSource = new ResourceSource(xmlReader, responseXslt);
        responseTemplates = transformerFactory.newTemplates(responseSource);
    }
}

public static String getFirstBodyElement(SOAPBody body) {
    for (Iterator<?> iterator = body.getChildElements(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Object child = iterator.next();
        if (child instanceof SOAPElement) {
            return ((SOAPElement) child).getTagName();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

3. In Configuration class add intercepter like this

```
public class ServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
public RequestTransformingInterceptor transformingInterceptor() {
    RequestTransformingInterceptor transformingInterceptor = new RequestTransformingInterceptor();
    Resource xslt = new ClassPathResource("/style/style.xslt", getClass());
    transformingInterceptor.setRequestXslt(xslt);
    try {
        transformingInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e, e);
    }
    return transformingInterceptor;
}
    public void addInterceptors(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") List interceptors) {
    interceptors.add(transformingInterceptor());

}
```

}

Comment: You my friend, are my hero. I've wasted days trying to get SpringWS to manage to parse a soap request with "multiref" nested children - was about to give up when I came across your post, so thank you! By the way, your stylesheet is missing the closing `</xsl:stylesheet>` but otherwise it worked perfectly